# Извлечь видимый текст с веб страницы. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy

У меня есть вот такой паук, который должен извлечь весь видимый контент со стартопой страницы википедии:

```
class OrphanSpider(CrawlSpider):
  start_urls = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"]
  name = "wikispider"
  os.mkdir("testT5")
  def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select("//body")
    items = []
    f1 = open("testT5/wiki.txt",'w')
    for site in sites:    
      item = OrphanageItem()
      item['id'] = site.select("//body//text()").extract()   
      items.append(item)
      plain_text= ''.join(items).strip()
      f1.write(str(plain_text))
    return plain_text
```

Но возникает вот такая ошибка:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, OrphanageItem found
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: `plain_text= ''.join(items).strip()` - join ожидает получить список строк. Попробуйте, например `plain_text= ''.join([str(item) for item in items]).strip()`. `''.join([1,2,3])` выдает ту же ошибку.

Comment: Это я понял, мне нужно решение проблмы)

Comment: так вот же: `plain_text= ''.join([str(item) for item in items]).strip()`. Возможно, придется определить метод `__str__()` в классе `OrphanageItem` (альтернативы: `__repr__`, `__unicode__`)

Comment: Вроде заработало, но в сохранившемся тексте теперь появились всякие символы юникода типо : u'\n\t\t\t\t', Как от них избавиться?

Comment: `\n\t` - это не символы Юникода, это символы табуляции и перевода строки. Если они были в исходном тексте - они там и остались. Уверены, что от них надо избавляться? Избавиться-то несложно...

Comment: `plain_text = plain_text.replace('\n', '')`

Comment: Да, мне нужен чисто видимый текст, без всякого форматирования. Вот сейчас у меня такие вещи в перемешку с видимым текстом: {'id': [u'\n\t\t', u'\n\t\t', u'\n\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t', u'\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n', u'\n\t\t\t', u'Main Page', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменяем строку:

```
plain_text= ''.join(items).strip()
```

на

```
plain_text= ''.join([str(item) for item in items]).strip()
```

Дело в том, что метод `join` ожидает на входе список строк и сам по себе не переводит элементы списка в строки.

Для того, чтобы удалить форматирование (тривиальный, хоть и не совсем корректный способ):

```
plain_text = plain_text.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ')
```

Недостаток этого способа в том, что в тексте останется несколько пробелов на месте где было что-то типа `'текст\n\t\t\tеще какой-то текст'`.
Можно это реализовать с регулярками, что-то типа:

```
plain_text = re.sub('\s+', ' ', plain_text)
```

(сам не пробовал, не было не нужды, надо тестить)

Если последние методы не приводят к желаемому результату нужно добавить метод `to_plain_text(self)` к классу OrphanageItem (либо внешнюю функцию, если нет доступа к классу), который будет выдавать конкретный элемент в виде "плоского", неформатированного текста, соответсвенно, поменяв `str(item)` на `item.to_plain_text()`.

Тут конкретные способы не зная содержимого класса описать невозможно.

Comment: В функциях, принимающих итераторы, можно передавать не генератор списка, а генераторное выражение, заодно избавившись от лишней пары скобок: `''.join(str(item) for item in items)` или просто использовав функцию `map`: `''.join(map(str, items))`